# Postgres database export and import, problem with $$PATH$$

Tags: database, postgresql, import, export

I am in the process of doing export and import with `postgres` database.

I had used the following command to take the backup of `postgres` db

```
C:\dirs> pg_dump -U postgres -p 15432 -W -F t cgate-next-demo > .\dbexport_10th_February_2022.tar
Password:*****
```

I have unzipped `dbexport_10th_February_2022.tar` file and proceeded with database import. As a initial step, I had dropped the database.

```
#drop database if exists "cgate-next-demo";
```

And I had recreated the empty database.

```
#create database "cgate-next-demo";
```

In order to do this, I have logged in to `psql` once,

```
C:\dirs> psql -U postgres -p 15432
Password for user postgres:*****
postgres=#
```

For database import I have used the following command.

```
C:\dirs> psql -U postgres -p 15432 -d cgate-next-demo <restore.sql
```

While I do that I have got the following error. I took this excerpt from console logs.

> ERROR:  could not open file "$$PATH$$/6052.dat" for reading: No such
> file or directory HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server
> process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as
> psql's \copy.

Can someone guide on what would've caused this issue.

Comment: Later I found `$$PATH$$` must be replaced with the folder under which exported data is available. I had opened `restore.sql` file and replace all the `$$PATH$$` string with the directory `C:\Anand\SE\postgres-db-backup\dbexport_10th_February_2022`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this in the wrong fashion. Rather than unpacking the archive, pass it as argument to `pg_restore`. That will do everything for you.